# Placing multiple histograms in a stack with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am trying to place multiple histograms in a vertical stack. I am able to get the plots in a stack but then all the histograms are in the same graph.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True, figsize=(20, 18))

n = 2

axes = ax.flatten()
for i, j in zip(range(n), axes):
    plt.hist(np.array(dates[i]), bins=20, alpha=0.3)


plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `for i, ax in zip(range(n), axes):`, `ax.hist(....)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 2x1 grid of axis objects. By directly looping over `axes.flatten()`, you are accessing one subplot at a time. You then need to use the corresponding axis instance for plotting the histogram.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True, figsize=(20, 18)) # axes here

n = 2

for i, ax in zip(range(n), axes.flatten()): # <--- flatten directly in the zip
    ax.hist(np.array(dates[i]), bins=20, alpha=0.3)
```

Your original version was also correct except the fact that instead of `plt`, you just should have used the correct variable i.e. `j` instead of `plt`

```
for i, j in zip(range(n), axes):
    j.hist(np.array(dates[i]), bins=20, alpha=0.3)
```